# bazel tensorflow protoc version mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, protoc

I tried to build a custom protocol buffer in bazel within tensorflow r1.12.0 (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC)), but keep running into the following error message

> This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
>   incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update your
>   headers.

Upon closer examination of the cause of the above error, I looked into the bazel-genfiles directly and found that for pre-existing pb.h files, such as examples.pb.h, the hardcoded bazel version is 3.6.0:

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3006000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 3006000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

But for the pb.h file of my own custom protocol buffer, it shows version 3.5:

```
#if GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERSION < 3005000
#error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
#error your headers.
#endif
#if 3005000 < GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_MIN_PROTOC_VERSION
#error This file was generated by an older version of protoc which is
#error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please
#error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
#endif
```

Thus the incompatibility.

Indeed, if I build examples.proto myself via the cc_proto_library rule like this,

```
cc_proto_library(
    name = "example_cc_protos",
    deps = [":example_protos"],
)
```

I also see versionn 3005000 in the generated examples.pb.h file, so the 3006000 pb.h file above was probably downloaded from a remote source.

My pip/protobuf shows version 3.6.1 and protoc --version also shows 3.6.1, so I suspected that the protobuf within bazel itself must be of version 3.5, leading to the above unfortunate hardcoding of 3005000.

I found that protobuf 3.6.1 became available since [bazel 0.17](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/0.17.2/third_party/protobuf/3.6.1); [similar link for bazel 0.16](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/0.16.1/third_party/protobuf/3.6.1) gives me a 404. Thus I tried installing bazel 0.17 using prebuilt installer on GitHub. But surprisingly the generated pb.h file still has 3005000 proto version hardcoded.

I then tried building bazel from the source, via

```
git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel.git
cd bazel
bazel build //src:bazel
alias bazel=bazel-bin/src/bazel
```

But that still gave me the same error.

I have also tried multiple versions of bazel, from 0.15.x to 0.18.x; higher versions fail to build tensorflow_model_server, so I have not tried. They all result in 3005000 for pb.h built from cc_proto_library bazel rule.

Official tensorflow doc says tf 1.12 was tested with bazel 0.15:
[image]

Finally if I build the .proto file with protoc directly, I do get 3006001 in the pb.h file, just to show that I installed protoc correctly.

**My question is** where does the 3005000 in the pb.h file come from? Is it gcc, bazel, tensorflow, protoc, or pip/protobuf ?

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by removing the following external dependency package from the 
tensorflow/WORKSPACE file:

```
# load("@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl", "closure_repositories")

# closure_repositories()
```

The reason is that the closure_repositories use protobuf 3.5, since 3.6 requires g++11 which is not universally available.