# This file was generated by a newer version of protoc

Tags: protocol-buffers, bazel

I am using bazel, proto and grpc in a C++ project with multiple packages.

One of the package doesn't use grpc but uses protobufs, and that is the one that creates the problem.

This is (the beginning) of the error message:

```bash
In file included from cc/tensorflow/plugin_primeclient/kernels/var.inc:7,
                 from cc/tensorflow/plugin_primeclient/kernels/kernels.cc:58:
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/interface/proto/resource_handle.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
   12 | #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
      |  ^~~~~
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/interface/proto/resource_handle.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
   13 | #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
      |  ^~~~~
bazel-out/aarch64-fastbuild/bin/cc/tensorflow/plugin/interface/proto/resource_handle.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
   14 | #error your headers.
      |  ^~~~~
```

What I don't understand is that this file is generated by bazel using protoc, how can it end up using different versions of protocol buffers?

Here is my WORKSPACE:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_proto",
    sha256 = "66bfdf8782796239d3875d37e7de19b1d94301e8972b3cbd2446b332429b4df1",
    strip_prefix = "rules_proto-4.0.0",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
        "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_proto/archive/refs/tags/4.0.0.tar.gz",
    ],
)
load("@rules_proto//proto:repositories.bzl", "rules_proto_dependencies", "rules_proto_toolchains")
rules_proto_dependencies()
rules_proto_toolchains()

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_grpc_grpc",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/grpc/grpc/archive/refs/tags/v1.44.0.tar.gz",
    ],
    sha256 = "8c05641b9f91cbc92f51cc4a5b3a226788d7a63f20af4ca7aaca50d92cc94a0d",
    strip_prefix = "grpc-1.44.0",
)
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_deps.bzl", "grpc_deps")
grpc_deps()
load("@com_github_grpc_grpc//bazel:grpc_extra_deps.bzl", "grpc_extra_deps")
grpc_extra_deps()
```

And the relevant BUILD:

```
cc_library(
    name = "interface",  # interface is used as a dependency for another package 
    hdrs = glob(["interface/**/*.h"]) + glob(["interface/**/*_impl.inc"]),
    includes = ["interface"],
    strip_include_prefix = "interface",
    deps = [":interface_cc_proto"],
    visibility = ["//cc/tensorflow:__subpackages__"],
)

cc_proto_library(
    name = "interface_cc_proto",
    deps = [":interface_proto"],
)

proto_library(
    name = "interface_proto",
    srcs = glob(["interface/**/*.proto"])
)
```

I would like to solve this mismatch issue.

**Edit:** I am running everything within a devcontainer using the [tensorflow image from arm dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/armswdev/tensorflow-arm-neoverse). I tried uninstalling `protoc` before running bazel, I had the exact same issue.

Comment: It is answered over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55290443/bazel-tensorflow-protoc-version-mismatch

Comment: It doesn't relate to my case. I edited the post to add info about the running environment

Comment: no one has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I came to know that there was a conflict between two versions of the protobuf installed via apt-get and from the source.
I checked via :

**for apt-get:**
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
protoc --version

**and for source:**
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
protoc --version

then removed the one installed through source,next I checked again and both were the same version.

Answer (score 0):

**Step to resolve this issue, when I type on terminal protoc --version, Its saying command not found. protoc version installed in my mac machine. But not able to get it. Its not able to find it**.

** Protoc Installed with this command:**

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-21.3-osx-universal_binary.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.3/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local 'include/*'
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/proto
```

For me issue was:-
This file was generated by a newer version of protoc. I was using Xcode, Pod and Using protoc in Swift Project.

In my mac machine protoc install at the path: usr/local/bin/protoc and headers  files at  usr/local/include.
Issue is terminal or xcode not able to get from this path

**Step 1.** Copy this path: usr/local/bin/

**Step 2.** Paste in this file(.zshrc) at path:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/

**Step 3.** Quit terminal windows

**Step 4.** protoc --version

Now it will print like this
libprotoc 3.21.3

**If you are facing this issue with Xcode 14.3 and Pods
Follow below steps**

Step 1. Remove  pods with this command: rm -rf Pods
Step 2. pod install

It will work.